# Javascript save current contents of object in another object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have:

```
var obj1 = {
    '0': 'a',
    '1': 'b'
    }

var obj2 = obj; // I want to create a new object with obj contents

obj1[2] = 'c' // Now I modify obj without modifying obj2

obj1 = obj2; // so I can restore obj later
```

However modifying obj also modificates obj2. How can I create a copy of obj1 that is independent of it?

Comment: You need to create a deep copy of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is JSON-compatible (i.e., does not contain any functions as values, nor references to DOM nodes, etc):

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a **deepCopy** of the object.

```
var obj1 = {
    '0': 'a',
    '1': 'b'
};

var obj2 = deepCopy(obj1);

obj1[2] = 'c'

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);

function deepCopy(obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sQnrA/1/)**